# Prevent IntelliJ IDEA from auto-opening my code while editing

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, development-environment

I'm trying to find a way to prevent IntelliJ from auto expanding my code while editing -
this drives me crazy (but worst of all - it wastes my time...).

The language I'm experiencing this behavior with is Javascript, and intellij's version is 14.1.6.

What happens is some functions are collapsed and while I'm writing more code
the IDE opens more and more functions (this might be due to code checking).

Any clue ?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too... Let me know if you find a solution!